# Zoom in on an image without losing quality

Tags: image-quality, zoom

Can i enlarge an image without losing quality? You know, like in cool movies people do.
Like so:
[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Given the aberrations the enlarged flower in the image is probably done with an actual magnifying glass.  A composite of two images- a macro for the magnifying glass image and a 'normal' shot for everything else is also a possibility.

Comment: Depends on whether we are talking about digital images, hard-copy print, or film. Many images can be enlarged somewhat. Some digital images can be enlarged many times if the resolution is high enough (extra pixel information exists), others cannot be enlarged or zoomed at all without losing quality.